# JQuery $.cookie SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

I am using JQuery $.cookie to save my application users token upon their login, then read users token each time they try to access any of the app features using the following code:

```
        var Token = '';
        var cookieContent = '';
        if(typeof $.cookie('MyAPP') === 'undefined'){
            cookieContent = '';
        }else{
           cookieContent = $.cookie('MyAPP');
           Token = JSON.parse(cookieContent); //Error here
           console.log('Token' + Token);
        }
```

My problem is that first time this code is executed, I get error:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

at JSON.parse, if I hit refresh to call this code again, it works normally without any problem. So I am wondering how I can avoid this error?

As far as I understand this error is caused because $.cookie is returning an [Object] which is not parsed by JSON but I am not sure why it is returning object first time the code is executed then work normally 2nd time? Also is there any way I can do to avoid this error? Thanks

Update: Here is how I save the cookie in the first place:

```
 function saveCookie(minutes, Token) {
   var date = new Date();
   var m = minutes;
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
   $.cookie.json = true;
   $.cookie("MyAPP", Token, { expires: date });     
}
```

Comment: The bug is probably hidden in the surrounding code, because what you posted here seems fine. (in a vacuum) Without the rest of the app code, for example where the cookie is written, we can't really help you.

Comment: @S.B. I don't think also that posting source code of an app of 50+ files will be helpful to this specific problem :) But I will update my question with code I used to save the cookie

Comment: Code for saving the cookie, added